# Can I allow another PSN user to play my Terraria world with a different PSN account when I’m not online?

Tags: ps4, terraria-console

We are both using the same console to play in split screen, but I created the world on my PSN account. Can I somehow share it so he can play on the same save with his account when I am not around?

Comment: Isn't the world saved offline too?

Answer (score 1):

Servers are linked to accounts so unless you are signed in and are in the world he cannot join.